# How to enable scrollbar for only last section in fullpage.js?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

How do I enable a scrollbar for only the last section in `fullpage.js`?

**I tried this:**

```
$("#section3").fullpage({
  scrollBar: true,
  fitToSection: false,
});
```

But it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fullpage.js option `scrollOverflow:true`.
It will only be applied to section which content is bigger than the viewport.

If your last section is the only one with a bigger content, you'll have scrolling bar only in the last section.

From [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **scrollOverflow:** (default false) defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section in case its content is bigger than the height of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin. Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the vendor plugin jquery.slimscroll.min and it should be loaded before the fullPage.js plugin.

Comment: that doesn't working for me, can you give me DEMO? in jsfiddle

Comment: This method doesn't work with Parallax.js (http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) they are in conflict and how to do this?

Comment: @VatexOfficial you didn't mention parallax in your question. You'd better create another question asking about it. Regarding the demo, you have [this one online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Comment: ok demo is good but what I must do? how to make srcolling like that for me?

Comment: As I said: Use the fullpage.js option `scrollOverflow:true`. Check [the source code of the demo](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrolling.html) if you don't know how. People can not learn for you. You'll have to put some effort.